# How to add input field inside form as per tab active using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add the input field dynamically as per tab active using `javascript/jquery`. I am giving my code below.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" id="cartabslist">
      <li class="active" id="Generaltab"><a href="#GENERAL" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#CARTYPES" data-toggle="tab">Types</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#CARTARIFF" data-toggle="tab">Tariff</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#PAYMENT" data-toggle="tab">Payment Methods</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="panel-footer">
      <input name="updatesettings" value="1" type="hidden">
      <input name="tariffsettings" value="1" type="hidden">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here I need when tab `General` is active then `<input name="updatesettings" value="1" type="hidden">` will add before submit button and if tab `Tariff` is active `<input name="tariffsettings" value="1" type="hidden">` will add before form and the previous one will remove using `Javascript or Jquery`.

Comment: You can add them both and add `disabled='disabled'` - then they won't be included in the form data with the post.  "Add/remove" with `.attr("disabled","disabled")` and `.attr("disabled", null)` (for IE compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add on more div before submit button

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" id="cartabslist">
      <li class="active" id="Generaltab"><a href="#GENERAL" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#CARTYPES" data-toggle="tab">Types</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#CARTARIFF" data-toggle="tab">Tariff</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#PAYMENT" data-toggle="tab">Payment Methods</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="panel-footer">
     <div id="hiddenDiv"></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Then you can check if General tab is active then you can append   to "hiddenDiv" else you can blank that div, vise versa for tariff tab

```
var selected = $("#cartabslist").tabs( "option", "selected" );
var selectedTabTitle = $($("#cartabslist li a")[selected]).text();
$("#hiddenDiv").html('');
if(selectedTabTitle == 'General')
{
   $("#hiddenDiv").append('<input name="updatesettings" value="1" type="hidden">');
}
else if(selectedTabTitle == 'Tariff')
{
   $("#hiddenDiv").append('<input name="tariffsettings" value="1" type="hidden">');
}
```

Comment: Its ok but like this both field will be there after multiple click on both tab.

Comment: You need to perform hidden input append functionality once you get click event ok tab

Comment: wont it be nice if we let the input field stay and only change the name of the input on click events?

Comment: Yes it would be nice as both input field have same value, but input filed is added for general and tariff tabs only so I prefer to add them separately

Answer (score 0):

Since you are willing to use jQuery, this can be done quite easily. Add a seperate class(in this case `inputSelector`) on which you want the functionality, and the name of the input you need, as a data(here `data-name`) to the item.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" id="cartabslist">
      <li class="inputSelector active" data-name='updatesettings'><a href="#GENERAL" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#CARTYPES" data-toggle="tab">Types</a></li>
      <li class="inputSelector" data-name='tariffsettings'><a href="#CARTARIFF" data-toggle="tab">Tariff</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#PAYMENT" data-toggle="tab">Payment Methods</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="panel-footer">
      <input name="updatesettings" id='someId' value="1" type="hidden">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And add the following js to the ready function:

```
$('.inputSelector').click(function(){
  $('#someId').prop('name',$(this).data('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help. And also, I have removed hidden property and have made some changes for demonstration purpose.

```js
let UICarTabsList = document.querySelector('#cartabslist');
  let UISettingsInput = document.querySelector('#settings-input');

  document.querySelector('#cartabslist #Generaltab').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    UISettingsInput.innerHTML = `<input name="updatesettings" value="1" type="" placeholder="genral">`;
  });

  UICarTabsList.querySelector('#tarifftab').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    UISettingsInput.innerHTML = `<input name="tariffsettings" value="2" type="" placeholder="tarrif">`;
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" id="cartabslist">
    <li class="nav-link active" id="Generaltab"><a href="#GENERAL" data-toggle="tab"> General</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#CARTYPES" data-toggle="tab"> Types</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link" id="tarifftab"><a href="#CARTARIFF" data-toggle="tab"> Tariff</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#PAYMENT" data-toggle="tab"> Payment Methods</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div class="panel-footer">
  <form action="" id="main-form" method="POST">
    <div id="settings-input"><input name="updatesettings" value="1" type="" placeholder="genral"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </form>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Also by default `General` tab is active.

Comment: you may need to remove the `display:none` property from `#main-form`, and also add that `updatesettings` input inside the `settings-input` div. I will edit this once i go home